# Selenium automation Launching internet explorer throughapptool app

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-iedriver

There is a case
When we have to open internet explorer through start menu with right click option `open with *apptool` and then launch the web page.

Is that possible through selenium??

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is just an interface that allows you to perform some actions and retrieve results from browser. For selenium to work you need to have driver in your %PATH%.

You don't test opening browser itself with selenium.